# Get files on controller with HttpRequest.Form.Files

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get files from controller with HttpContext.Request.Form.Files
but im taking this error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
   at HasarTespit.Controllers.HomeController.Index(Order arr) in C:\Users\sberk\OneDrive\Masaüstü\HasarTespit2\HasarTespit\HasarTespit\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 206
```

This is my jQuery and controller:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromBody] Order arr)
    {     
        var files = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        return RedirectToAction("..");       
    }
```

```
function sepeteEkle(id) {
   
    var arr = { plaka:plaka,motorno: motorno, marka: marka, model: model, modelversiyonu: modelversiyonu, modelyili: modelyili, saseno: saseno, kmsaat: kmsaat, kasatipi: kasatipi, unvan: unvan, adres: adres, ilce: ilce, vergidairesi: vergidairesi, telno: telno, soforu: soforu, il: il, vergino: vergino, gsm1: gsm1, gsm2: gsm2, policeturu: policeturu, sigortasirketi: sigortasirketi, policeno: policeno, polbastar: polbastar, kazatarihi: kazatarihi, ihbartarihi: ihbartarihi, aracaaitnotlar: aracaaitnotlar, zeyilno: zeyilno, zeyiltarihi: zeyiltarihi, eksperler: eksperler, tahteslimtarihi: tahteslimtarihi, tahhasartutari: tahhasartutari, dosyano: dosyano, parcalar: data }
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            url: '/Home/Index',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        });
}
```

Comment: The request url in ajax is `AddRowsToMarket`, but the provided controller action is `Index`, is there any relationship between them?

Comment: @mj1313 it was my bad. so sory for this. i edited now.

Comment: Ok, can you show the `Order` class, also the request contentType is json but why you try to get the file from form?

Comment: There is a basket logic in the project. I had to. I have to show it in the project. Otherwise I can't tell. Also, the "Order" class has nothing to do with the issue. My goal is to get data via "httprequest".

Comment: I am afraid you can not do this, this request doesn't conatin form data, and this is the reason of the error.